# Mysql inner join data not working

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables data i need to display second table data also here to compare name is common in two tables i am fetching with name but it is not working.

table1 fields are id,name,email
table2 fields are id,name,gender

i need to display data like in one column as name,email,gender

here is code

```
$query = "(select name,email from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name)";
$fetch = mysql_query($query);

while($list = mysql_fetch_assoc($fetch))
{
$name = $list['name'];
$email = $list['email'];
$gender = $list['gender'];

echo "Name:" . $name . "Email:" . $email . "Gender:" . $gender;
}
```

Comment: What is the issue actually you are facing now??

Comment: while fetching line coming error mysql_fetch_assoc expecting array boolean given.

Comment: Your query are incorrect. It must be `select name,email,gender from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name`. And you forgot to add mysql_query function.

Comment: you can't select columns without table name in join so you need to edit your query like select table1.name, table1.email, table2.gender.

Answer (score 2):

You are selecting name and email ,so define it that from wich table you are getting these values:

Like This:

```
table1.name,table1.email,table2.gender
```

Change Query With This:

```
$query = "(select table1.name,table1.email,table2.gender  from table1 LEFT JOIN table2 ON table1.name=table2.name)";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$query = "(SELECT t1.name,t1.email, t2.gender FROM from table1 t1, table2 t2 where t1.name = t2.name)"
```